# Converting timeline vector animation into bitmap sequence

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a task to convert a FlashIDE made timeline animation (which uses lots of filters and stuff) into the same sequence of bitmaps at runtime with code, with the same duration of each frame etc. in order to improve performance and re-use this bitmaps anytime from the pool.
**Important**: I must obtain those animations from swf which I first load in the main app.

Is there any out-of-the-box solution for this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use the Sprite Sheet Export: https://helpx.adobe.com/flash/using/create-sprite-sheet.html

Comment: The thing is I have to grab those animations from swf file which I load first.

Comment: Ok, well you will have to playback the SWF and draw each frame using `BitmapData/draw()`. You *might* be able to use `gotoAndStop()` through each frame so you don't have to actually wait for the frames to play back. This process is going to be a bit heavy for the runtime, though, which is why the "standard" way would be to do this beforehand if you can.

Answer (score 0):

This is the wrong approach. Converting an animation into a bitmap sequence will require a lot of CPU and memory and might even idle your app if the animation is big. 
The best approach is to create a converter class that will load (or obtain) the swf. This converter class will mimic the swf playhead with the same number of frames but will not draw to bitmap all frames, only the ones that are played. For example if you call on that class gotoAndStop(32), that class will check if that frame has been drawn and if not it will draw it then display it. Same thing if you call play (which is gotoAndStop(index++)). The goal is to draw only the frames that need to be displayed on a per need basis. You can either dispose frames that have been played or keep them in memory but for big animation dispose will be better.